# Infer type from tuple contents

Tags: typescript, generics

Say I have a generic tuple type:

```
type MyTuple<A, B> = [A, B]
```

The following works, because I give it the generic types:

```
const thing2: MyTuple<number, string> = [20, 'hello']
```

I want to use it like this, but it gives an error:

```
const thing1: MyTuple = [20, 'hello'] // -> Generic type 'MyTuple' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

I don't understand why it needs the generic args in this instance - I rarely have to specify the generic type when using `map` for example.

[Code here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAqBXMAbCAeAggGigIQD4oBeKAbR3wF0AoGgYwHsA7AZ2CmAAsBLZgcwCMALlgJkaEuQBMABlwByLhBQpGC2gxbtOvAdNFwkqDM0QBbAEYQATrnY2+-IqTJzFy1eqpA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types like `MyTuple<A, B>` do *not* get inferred by the compiler.

There was a request for this ability in [microsoft/TypeScript#30120](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30120), which was closed as a duplicate of the longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Maybe in some future version of TypeScript you could write `const thing1: MyTuple<infer, infer> = [20, 'hello']` and it would work how you want.  But for now (TS4.7 and below) this isn't possible.

---

On the other hand, type parameters for generic *functions* do get inferred by the compiler when you call them (like the `map()` method on arrays, for example).  This means you can work around your issue by creating a generic helper identity function:

```
type MyTuple<A, B> = [A, B]
const myTuple = <A, B>(t: MyTuple<A, B>) => t;
```

And instead of writing `const x: MyTuple<XXX,YYY> = y`, you write `const x = myTuple(y)`:

```
const thing1 = myTuple([20, 'hello']);
// const thing1: MyTuple<number, string>
```

Now `thing1` has been inferred as being type `MyTuple<number, string>` as desired.  It might not be optimal to have this no-op function, but it's the closest we can get to what you want for now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAqBXMAbCAeAggGigIQD4oBeKAbR3wF0AoAYwHsA7AZ2CgFsFk0SotchABTAAXLG6oMlQgEoSRYAG4a9ZmyjAAFgEsmAcwCMfLkilCyAJgAMuAORaIKFAztVZKgPSeojVu209I3E4MzR0JkQOACMIACdcNjigglUgA)

Comment: We can spread the type to get the inferred tuple types in this identity function
`const tup = <T extends unknown[]>(t: [...T]) => t`

`const thing1 = tup([20, 'hello'])`

Answer (score 0):

You defined a generic type without default values.

`MyTuple` has no meaning without its 2 generic parameter.

---

```
type MyTuple<A = number, B = string> = [A, B]

const thing1: MyTuple = [20, 'hello']
```

This example works for example, but it's probably not what you were loooking for.